# Send emails to multiple recipients in a short time in PHP

Tags: php, email, debian

I need a program in technology php to send emails to multiple recipients in a short time. I have a database of approx. 50,000 people.

I wrote the script in php uses phpmailler and I have smtp server on debian, but the program is a little slow. Sends some 20,000 e-mails for the night.

Are there any php scripts that can quickly send? Give someone github?

Comment: This is better done by paying for an email sending service such as Sendgrid. Even if you get your own program working at the scale you want, you risk getting blacklisted as a spammer, and then people will not get your emails.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like rappitMQ or GearMan, for gearman they have an example of sending emails actually in PHP , here are the sites

https://www.rabbitmq.com/
http://gearman.org/